# Algorithm for Longest Square Substring

Tags: java, string, algorithm, combinatorics, words

I am seeking an algorithm (in Java) that will allow user to input a string and the program will return the longest square substring. For example, if user inputs 'poofoofoopoo' then the program returns 'Longest Square Substring: foofoo'. If anyone can write such an algorithm, I would be very appreciative!

My first thought was to modify the Manacher algorithm which returns the longest palindromic substring (in linear time).

Here is the Java code that I have for the Manacher algorithm:

```js
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class LongestPalindrome 
{
 // function to pre-process string 
 public String preProcess(String str) 
 {
  int len = str.length();
  if (len == 0)
  {
   return "^$";
  }
  String s = "^";
  for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
  {
   s += "#" + str.charAt(i);    
  }
  s += "#$";
  return s;
 }
 
 // function to get largest palindrome sub-string 
 public String getLongestPalindrome(String str)
 {
  // pre-process string 
  char[] s = preProcess(str).toCharArray();
  int N = s.length;
  int[] p = new int[N + 1];
  int id = 0; 
  int mx = 0;
  for (int i = 1; i < N - 1; i++) 
  {
   p[i] = 0;
   while (s[i + 1 + p[i]] == s[i - 1 - p[i]])
   {
    p[i]++;
   }
   if (i + p[i] > mx) 
   {
    mx = i + p[i];
    id = i;
   }
  }
  // length of largest palindrome 
  int maxLen = 0;
  // position of center of largest palindrome 
  int centerIndex = 0;
  for (int i = 1; i < N - 1; i++) 
  {
   if (p[i] > maxLen) 
   {
    maxLen = p[i];
    centerIndex = i;
   }
  }
  // starting index of palindrome 
  int pos = (centerIndex - 1 - maxLen)/2;
  return str.substring(pos , pos + maxLen);        
 }
 
 // Main Function
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
 {    
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
  System.out.println("LongestPalindrome Algorithm Test\n");
  System.out.println("\nEnter String");
  String text = br.readLine();
  
  LongestPalindrome m = new LongestPalindrome(); 
  String LongestPalindrome = m.getLongestPalindrome(text); 
  System.out.println("\nLongest Palindrome: "+ LongestPalindrome);    
 }    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Adjacent substrings and palindromes are quite different, I think.

One method to find the longest adjacent substring is to keep an array of indices. At the beginning, this is just an enumeration from 0 to (but not including) `str.length`. Sort this array, such that

```
str.substr(a) < str.substr(b)
```

which in your example yields:

```
[3]     foofoopoo
[6]     foopoo
[2]     ofoofoopoo
[5]     ofoopoo
[1]     oofoofoopoo
[4]     oofoopoo
[7]     oopoo
[8]     opoo
[9]     poo
[0]     poofoofoopoo
[11]    o
[10]    oo
```

Then walk through the array and look for adjacent entries `a` and `b` where

```
str.substr(a, a + d) == str.substr(b, b + d)
```

with

```
d = abs(a - b)
```

Then the string

```
str.substr(min(a, b), min(a, b) + 2 * d)
```

is a candidate. Make sure not to go beyond the string's end when creating substrings.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a subquadratic complexity to the problem, and unfortunately I can't comment to the other answer. Are we sure that looking for adjacent entries in the sorted suffix array is enough?

For example, if `s = aaaa`, the longest square substring is `s` itself, but the entries in the suffix array that interest us are `[2] aa`, and `[0] aaaa`, but they aren't consecutive, being separated by `[1] aaa`.

The "cousin" problem (Longest Square Subsequence) appears to be much better documented: https://arxiv.org/pdf/2006.00216.pdf

Are there any other resources on this problem?

Edit: The [Main-Lorentz](https://cp-algorithms.com/string/main_lorentz.html) `O(n log n)` algorithm for finding all squares in a string.